# Impact on space on class / id

Tags: html, css

What will be the impact, if we add some extra space in id or class in HTML.

Like if we write like this,

```
<div class="              class1" id="       id">This is a div</div>
```

Will the CSS or JS break?

Will there be any effect on class or id selection in JavaScript or CSS?

Comment: Did you try?....

Comment: of-course I have tried... Just want to understand why rule of css working.. but with id it doesn't...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
/*not working*/
console.log(document.getElementById("id"));
/*working*/
console.log(document.getElementById("       id"));
/*working*/
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("class1")[0]);
/*working*/
console.log(document.querySelector('.class1'));
```

```css
/*working*/
.class1{
color: red;
}
/*working*/
div[id='       id'] { 
  text-align: center;
}
/*not working*/
#id{
background-color: yellow;
}
/*not working*/
#       id{
font-size: 300%;
}
```

```html
<div class="              class1" id="       id">This is a div</div>
```

> Developers always make it work. :)

Comment: Any idea why class selector works while id selector does not?

Answer (score 0):

A class can have space separated classeS and ID needs to be unique. You are not actually allowed spaces but the browser allows them anyway

So spaces in the className are handled, it is expected to have space delimited classes

The ID with spaces has the spaces as part of the ID - it is tolerated by the browser if you use the spaces in accessing it

```js
var byCl = document.querySelector(".class1"),
byId = document.getElementById("id"),
byIdSpaces = document.getElementById("       id")
console.log(byCl); // ok
console.log(byId); // null
console.log(byIdSpaces); // ok
console.log("byCl",byCl.innerText)
console.log("byIdSpaces",byIdSpaces.innerText)
```

```html
<div class="              class1" id="       id">This is a div</div>
```